# Cannot register remote control to Selenium Hub

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I got this problem when I tried to register the remote control to Selenium Hub.

Here is the ip info:
RC: 172.16.0.90
HUB: 172.16.0.121

Step:
1. "ant launch-hub" on Hub Machine
2. "ant -Dport=5555 -Dhost=172.16.0.90 -Dhuburl=http://172.16.0.121:4444 lanuch-remote-control" on RC Machine.

The error message is that "Could not contact the Selenium HUb at 'http://localhost:4444' : Connection refused..."

Why it is connecting to "localhost"?  Did I do the wrong step or wrong command? Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is `-DhubURL`, not `-Dhuburl`.

Comment: Hello, I changed the command to "-DhubURL", but it still doesn't work. Any other idea?? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What version of Selenium Grid are you using?

Comment: Selenium Gird 1.0.8, thanks. And, I already closed the firewall on both machines. Do I need to have static IP address, although these two machines are in the same network?

Comment: No need for a static IP address.  The firewall issue is interesting though.  Can you access http://172.16.0.121:4444 in a browser from your node?

Comment: When I tried"172.16.0.121:4444", I got the error message HTTP ERROR: 404
NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/

Powered by Jetty://

But, however, when I opened this link "http://172.16.0.121"4444/console", I can see the hub status.

It's kinda weird...

Comment: That's fine.  I just wanted to establish that the node could communicate with the hub.  Any chance you could copy & paste verbatim the actual command you're using to start-up your hub.  What you're using in your question has a bunch of typos, so it can't possibly be what you're really using.

Comment: I wanted the command you're using to start the remote control, not the hub.

Comment: @user836112 Enter http://172.16.0.121:4444/console link in address bar of browser and verify that hub has launched. if not in ur pc may be some other java must be running.